# MariaDB / MySQL - LOAD XML INFILE (Errcode: 2 - “No such file or directory”)

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am using MariaDB (mySQL Variant) to attmept to load XML data from a file into a table. When I use the "LOAD XML INFILE" command from the mySQL Shell I get the (Errcode: 2 - “No such file or directory”). The file path is correct.

If I use the command LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to load a CSV file in the same directory, it works without a hitch, making me think its not any type of security permission as far as the database opening the file.

Any suggestions on what else to check? I've already confirmed that the XML is in one of the three supported formats, although I would assume I would receive a different error for that.

I've also tried putting these both in the mySQL Data folder with no change in behavior.

**Command Ran Successfully for CSV InFile**

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\TestData\\testfile.CSV' 
INTO TABLE `testimport` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' 
 ESCAPED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' IGNORE 1 LINES (`column1`, `column2`);
```

**Load XML File that is throwing an error of file cannot be located:**

```
LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\TestData\\testfile.xml'
 INTO TABLE testimport
 ROWS IDENTIFIED BY '<testimport>';
```

As a note, I have also created a table for the XML version called testimport with columns named column1 and column2 which I'm using as my source for fields for the XML input and they match the file column names.

Comment: If the client and server are on different machines, you need `LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE`.

Comment: The file is local to the server (and on the same drive as the mySQL command prompt).

Comment: Then it should work if the pathname is correct.

Comment: LOAD XML LOCAL INFILE resolved the issue. Thank you.